# How to show login status on redirecting to home page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using http only cookies for authentication in the nodejs backend, so I can't access them from `document.cookies`. I have a backend API to show authentication status. This API is being called in the `useEffect` of the root layout. When I load the page that API is being called and my username is being shown if I have valid cookies.

```js
const [userName, setUserName] = useState();
const [userId, setUserId] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const showMe = async () => {
    let res = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/showMe",
      {
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );
    console.log("Entered in root useEffect");
    setUserName(res.data.user.name);
    setUserId(res.data.user.userId);
  };
  showMe();
}, [userName, userId]);
```

Now when I press the log in button an API request is done on the server with appropriate credentials as a result my cookies are generated. I am using a `react-router` action in the `"/login"` path to send that login request. If response is ok I am using `redirect` to return to home page.

```js
export const action = async ({ request, params }) => {
  console.log(params);
  const data = await request.formData();
  const loginData = {
    email: data.get("email"),
    password: data.get("password"),
  };

  console.log(loginData);

  let url = "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/login";

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(loginData),
    credentials: "include",
  });

  if (response.status === 422) {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }

  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log(response);
    throw json({ message: "Could not login." }, { status: 500 });
  }

  return redirect("/");
};
```

Now after being redirected to homepage my login status is not updated as neither root layout is being reloaded on redirect nor the `useEffect` inside of it is called. When I manually reload the page one more time I can see my login status. How can I fix it so that I don't have to do that extra reload?

Routing object

```
{
  path: "/",
  element: <RootLayout />,
  children: [
    { index: true, element: <Home /> },
    {
      path: "login",
      element: <Login></Login>,
      action: action,
    },
    {
      path: "logout",
      element: <Logout></Logout>,
      action: logoutAction,
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the routing code that renders the routes and calls the loaders/actions?

Comment: Okay i have edited to add the routing code

Comment: So you've some `useEffect` in `RootLayout` that you want to be triggered again after logging in? Can you share also the routed components as part of the complete [mcve]? You probably also don't want `userName` and `userId` to be the `useEffect` dependencies since that's what the effect updates. It can cause render looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue you're facing is related to the fact that the useEffect in your RootLayout component is not being triggered after a successful login redirect. This is because React Router doesn't automatically re-render a component when the route changes but the component is already mounted.

To solve this issue and update the login status without manually reloading the page, you can use React Router's useLocation hook to detect changes in the route and trigger the showMe function when the route changes. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function RootLayout() {
  const location = useLocation(); // Get the current route location

  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const showMe = async () => {
      let res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/showMe', {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      console.log('Entered in root useEffect');
      setUserName(res.data.user.name);
      setUserId(res.data.user.userId);
    };

    // Call showMe whenever the route changes
    showMe();
  }, [location]); // Add location to the dependency array

  // ... rest of your component code
}
```